# Javascript regexp match with exception

Tags: javascript, regex

The input is an absolute path for example:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/normalize
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bobcat/index.js
```

I want to create a regex that matches EVERYTHING except when "bobcat" was found in the string:

This is what I got to match everything:

```
var pattern = /node_modules/g;
var matches = pattern.test(input);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's better to use two simple regular expressions than a single complex one.

Comment: how about a negation? `var pattern = /bobcat/, matches = !pattern.test(input);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex:

```
/node_modules(?!.*\/bobcat\/)/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI1gF2/3)

`(?!.*\/bobcat\/)` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if `/bobcat/` comes after `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

Make an if/else statement and check if /bobycat/ matches. Put your code in the else part.